# Adding string to Structures in C

Tags: c, structure

I'm a beginner in C and am having some trouble with structures in C. Here is my code;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct rec
{
    char i;
    char b;
    char j;
} ;

int main()
{

 struct rec *p;
 p=(struct rec *) malloc (sizeof(struct rec));
 (*p).i='hello';
 (*p).b='world';
 (*p).j ='there';
 printf("%c %c %c\n",(*p).i,(*p).b,(*p).j);

 free(p);
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

The out of this is;
 o d e

How can I pass in the whole word, rather than just one letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the structure members as `char *`:

```
struct rec
{
    char *i;
    char *b;
    char *j;
} ;
```

and use `printf` with `%s`:

```
printf("%s %s %s\n",(*p).i,(*p).b,(*p).j);
```

Also, you need to replace `'` with `"`: `(*p).j ="there";` and if you assign string literals (which may not be modified), change the struct members to `const`:

```
struct rec
{
    const char *i;
    const char *b;
    const char *j;
} ;
```

Comment: The string assignments will also need to be enclosed in double quotes rather than single quotes. Technically the structure members should be declared `const char *` based on the original code sample.

Comment: The original version didn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

The common string type in C is `char*`, which means a pointer to an array of `char` elements. C marks the end of a string with a special character `\0`. Those strings are generally called 0-terminated strings.

To save one in your structure you need something like this:

```
struct foo {
  char* words;
};
```

Character literals (a.k.a inline strings) have the type `const
char[n]` where `n` is the length of the string plus one element for
the null-terminator, so you cannot assign a character literal to a
`char*`. You will need to allocate `strlen(x) + 1` `char` elements and
then copy the contents of the string literal into this memory. Don't
forget to free it.

Maybe you should attempt to understand pointers and arrays first.